# Rails: how to make elegant calls with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User model and a Movie model and a MovieRatings model. Users have_many Movies through MovieRatings and vice versa.

A Movie Rating has a user_id, movie_id, and wants_to_see. wants_to_see is a boolean. Is there a simple way to get a user's list of movies where wants_to_see = true?

`user.movies.where(wants_to_see: true)` gets me a AssociationRelation object. `user.movie_ratings.where(wants_to_see: true)` gets me a list of of MovieRating objects which I then need to find the associated movie.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this a couple of ways. You could create a function that returns the movies that a user wants to

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movie_ratings
  has_many :movies, through: :movie_ratings

  def wants_to_see_movies
    self.movies.where(movie_ratings: { wants_to_see: true } )
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you could create an additional association using `has_many` for the "want to see" movies

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movie_ratings
  has_many :movies, through: :movie_ratings
  has_many :wants_to_see_movies, -> { where(movie_ratings: { wants_to_see: true } ) },
                                 through: :movie_ratings,
                                 source: movie
  end
end
```

Frankly, I'm not sure which solution is better/more recommended, but in either case, when you want to get all the movies a user wants to see,

```
@movies = @user.wants_to_see_movies
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I wasn't sure if I was missing something in my association setup

Comment: No problem! I'm glad to help.